# Looping through table and changing values in jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my tablestructure in jsp

```
<table id="servicetable">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><label id="servicename">somelabel</label></td>
<td><label id="status">RUNNING </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><label id="servicename2">somelabel</label></td>
<td><label id="status">RUNNING </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><label id="servicename3">somelabel</label></td>
<td><label id="status">RUNNING </label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I have to change the value of "RUNNING" to "STOPPED" if my value of "servicename" first td matches another string. Below is the code

```
     var $all_td_in_a_table = $("#servicetable td:nth-child(1)");//to get all first td's

                  $all_td_in_a_table.each(function(){                  
                       labelText_servicename = $("#servicename").text();
                       labelText_servicename=$.trim(labelText_servicename);
                       if(labelText_servicename.toLowerCase() ==="ABC"){
                       labelText = $("#status").text();
                       $("#status").text("TEST");
                       }
});
```

I see the variable "all_td_in_a_table" has list of all first td's, but my .each loop is always giving me the first td. Please help.

Comment: You need to iterate over each tr and process it, don't use ids as they are repeated

Comment: ID should be unique change `status` to class instead

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Can you help me with more details

Comment: @guradio, Thanks, but my initial problem seems to be iterating through the td's. I am always getting " labelText_servicename" from the first td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique. Where you have duplicates, if you use `$("#status")` that will just select the first one. You should use classes instead. That is, change this:

```
<label id="status">RUNNING </label>
```

...to this:

```
<label class="status">RUNNING </label>
```

As far as updating the status within the same row as the corresponding text value, you can use DOM navigation methods to stay within the same row. I would use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the parent tr element, then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to go back down to that row's status.

Note that within the `.each()`, you can refer to the current element with `this`. So all of that in context:

```js
$("#servicetable td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
  var currentItem = $(this);
  if (currentItem.text().toUpperCase() === "ABC") {
    currentItem.closest("tr").find(".status").text("STOPPED");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="servicetable">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label id="servicename">somelabel</label></td>
    <td><label class="status">RUNNING </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label id="servicename2">ABC</label></td>
    <td><label class="status">RUNNING </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label id="servicename3">somelabel</label></td>
    <td><label class="status">RUNNING </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label id="servicename2">ABC</label></td>
    <td><label class="status">RUNNING </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that you could also give your `servicenameX` fields a common class and then select by that instead of `#servicetable td:nth-child(1)`:

```
$("#servicetable .servicename").each(function() {
  // function body as above
```

...because then if you restructured your table to put that value in a different column you wouldn't have to change your selector. You'll notice in the working code above I don't actually use the `servicenameX` id values at all.

Other than what I already covered above to get a working solution, your code didn't work because within the each loop you only ever tested the value of the first row's `$("#servicename")`, plus you were using `.toLowerCase()` and then comparing with `"ABC"`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution and above all such a detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You just need to change .toLowerCase() to .toUpperCase(), and use the index, element paramteres :

```
$("#servicetable td:nth-child(1)").each(function(i,e) {
    labelText_servicename = $.trim($(e).text());
    if (labelText_servicename.toUpperCase() === "ABC") {
        $(e).closest('td').next().find('#status').html("TEST");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cj0xLc4s/4/

Comment: this code is working only for row1, if I change the 3rd row name to ABC it does not work, That is exactly the problem I am facing. "labelText_servicename" is always returning the first td

Comment: Use the index, element parameters to grab your elements. See my update.